# Keep bone rotated in-between two other bones?

Tags: constraints

I would like to keep a bone rotated in-between Bone 1 and Bone 2, shown in the screenshot. What types of constraints do I need to add to the bone to accomplish this? What about the parenting?
I have tried numerous combinations and cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I parented it to Bone 2. And added Copy Rotation constraint from Bone 1 in LOCAL space with 50% influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the method you mentioned works, it can get messy especially if you want more influences on one bone. Here is a method which is simple and easy to read.

An advantage is, that the hierarchy and bone orientation doesn't matter since it uses World Space constraints.

1. Duplicate the *between* bone and rename it with suffixes of the other bones.
   [image]
2. Add **Copy Rotation** constraints from both duplicated joints onto the *between joint*.
   [image]
3. Set the influence of the second copy rotation constraint to 0.5. The *between* bone is now equally influenced by the other two.
   [image]
4. Parent the *between_end* bone to the *end* bone.
   Parent the *between_start* bone to the *start* bone.
   The *between* bone is now influenced by the original bone. But we're still using World Space constraints but don't have to worry about the orientations.[image]

The rig holds various poses. Parenting can be changed freely as long as nothing is parented to the between bone (cyclic dependency).

[image]

The rig will break, if the angle of the original bones is more than 180°.

[image]

[image]

I recommend using *World Space* constraints with duplicates, because you are free to change the orientation later on. With *local space* constraints the bones have to be oriented the same, which is not always given.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried your approach and it is working now. Do you generally recommending avoiding using constrains that operate in local or pose space? Is it best practice to try to operate in World Space?

Comment: @TTTTTTa I added a last paragraph concerning local space constraints. There are several other reasons, but if your method works, use it. If something breaks after changes later on, double check the constraints and parent relations.